# Custom ExceptionHandler for HttpMessageNotReadableException in Spring Data REST

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

When POSTing an invalid JSON to a Spring Data REST (Version 2.2.2) Resource, an HttpMessageNotReadableException is thrown and the following json is returned:

```
{
    "cause": {
        "cause": {
            "cause": null,
            "message": "Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@646d9de6; line: 2, column: 20]"
        },
        "message": "Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@646d9de6; line: 2, column: 20] (through reference chain: gr.bytecode.exceptionhandling.domain.Book[\"name\"])"
    },
    "message": "Could not read JSON: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@646d9de6; line: 2, column: 20] (through reference chain: gr.bytecode.exceptionhandling.domain.Book[\"name\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@646d9de6; line: 2, column: 20] (through reference chain: gr.bytecode.exceptionhandling.domain.Book[\"name\"])"
}
```

**Is there a sensible way to override this behavior and return a custom error message?**

**Here's what I've tried so far:**

I added a custom `@ExceptionHandler` for that Exception but it never gets invoked:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
            HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status) {

        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage("some error");
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errorMessage, headers, status);
    }
}
```

*ErrorMessage is a simple POJO.*

It seems that the `AbstractRepositoryRestController` of the Spring Data REST, at line #97 defines a method that has precedence:

```
@ExceptionHandler({ HttpMessageNotReadableException.class })
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<ExceptionMessage> handleNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
    return badRequest(e);
}
```

I also tried to extend `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` but similarly, it is also not advised.

*Using: Spring Data REST 2.2.2 and Spring Boot 1.2.2*

ta.

**Update:** [Demo maven project available on github](https://github.com/dbalaouras/spring-exception-handling)

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this would be, to extend the `CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler` with `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` as you did with one change:

Instead of returning `ResponseEntity`you can call `handleExceptionInternal` method that is provided by `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. This method along with several other parameters, also takes in a body parameter. The body parameter can be set with your custom Error object.

For example:

```
ErrorInfo er = new ErrorInfo(request.getDescription(false), ex.getLocalizedMessage());
return handleExceptionInternal(ex, er, headers, status, request);
```